# How to know the external ip address of my gateway?

Tags: networking, router, lan

In my office network i unknowingly changed a setting of my gateway of lan network .. I had set my phone's ip address under a section in setting which states that.. Only this ip can login to the network.. And the ip which i filled in was of my phone which is connected to my office wifi network.. Due to this reason none of the computer in the lan network can access the router's login page.. I had used the gui interface.. So now i need to know my lan's router external ip address.. So thar i can access the router login page on my phone

Comment: Use something like http://ipchicken.com/ or http://www.findmyipaddress.com/. That will show you your external ip address.

Comment: Many router devices and most firewall devices are accessible through SSH, you can use programs like putty to make a connection to internal IP and change settings on the device that way.

Answer (score 0):

There are many sites on the Internet that will show you the external IP address of an Internet-facing router. [WhatIsMyIP](http://www.whatismyip.com) is one I regularly use. To determine the external IP address, view one of those sites from a browser running on a computer or some other device on the LAN side of that router. The site will see the external IP address for the router and show it to you.

Comment: The site u have mentioned will show my ip(one of the lan pc i am using)  i guess..  Not my routers